# fix "Firefox ... not responding" error

Tags: firefox

When I run

```
firefox --new-window <url> &
```

Firefox starts.  When I run it again, I get an error dialog reading:

> Firefox is already running, but is not responding.  To use Firefox, you must first close the
> existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile.

The expected behavior is that a second window opens on the same web page.

How do I fix this?

Note that I do **not** want instructions on how to kill the existing Firefox, or to remove lock files.  Everything else about it is working fine.  It just isn't taking the remote command.

Comment: Do you use multiple profiles with firefox ? Maybe you have multiple instances of firefox running ? Maybe the problem is related with the OS ?

Comment: @Marco  After the first failure, I deleted all profiles and made a new one.  No help.  Made a second profile, no help.  OS issues? maybe, but what should I try?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how firefox handles this and it works on my system. Ask somebody of the firefox developer or try debugging it: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that they replaced the classic X-based ICCCM-conformant open URL command with something `dbus` based.

So if you remove dbus, you get this error.

Pity.